# Is there a way to access the my clippings kindle from amazon website?

Tags: kindle

Context; I use kindle to read pdf files which i then hight passages from and add notes as part of research work flow. On the amazon website i can see the highlights for books i've purchased but not any of the pdf docs i have sent to my kindle using the 'convert' method of email a document in.

I can manually transfer these using a USB cable and copying 'My Clippings.txt' file.

Question: Does the 'My Clippings.txt' get stored in the cloud when the kindle syncs, if so is there an API or means of accessing this.

Reason for question: If I lose the kindle do I lose all notes I haven't backed up?

Comment: Did you find a solution to problem? I would quite interesting myself

Comment: No, to the best of my knowledge the file isn't synced to the cloud.

Answer (score 4):

**Solution**

Through this URL, you'll get all your books' highlights: https://read.amazon.com/notebook

**Issue**

Unfortunately I can't find a page where we can get all the highlights.
It is only available per book.

Comment: It seems like this only works for books bought from Amazon, not sideloaded books

Answer (score 1):

Use a private github repo to version your clippings file. Thats what I do.